# writing a test to prove a tic tac toe ai is unbeatable

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, minimax

I've created a tic tac toe web app (express angular) that implements the minimax algorithm to create an unbeatable AI, but now I'm wondering how do I write a test in jasmine (yes I know I'm doing it backwards by writing the test last instead of first) that can prove the AI is unbeatable?

would I need to create two instances of the AI and have it dual itself or a brute force so that the test would always result in a draw?

My understanding of the minimax algorithm is not great, but I feel like this kind of test would create an infinite loop (how many games would the test have to play to be satisfied that the AI is unbeatable?)

Is this a good way to go (AI vs AI or brute force vs AI) or is there a better way to test this kind of thing?

Comment: Why don't you try a match against a confirmed perfect engine? If your engine doesn't loose the match, you can be almost certain that it's unbeatable. (Enemy Plays perfect but can't win => your program played perfect as well)